# Asp.Net Core make Route parameter empty and send query parameters

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller with a GET method as follows:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("customer/{custId}")]
 public ActionResult GetCustomers([FromRoute]string custId, string prodId= "", string tagNo = "")
 {
 }
```

I want this to work like:

```
 /api/customer/123  -- where it returns the data for customer id =123
 /api/customer      -- where it returns all customers
 /api/customer?prodId=xyz  --where it returns data for productId=xyz
 /api/customer?tagNo=xyz123
```

But currently, it only works in the following way:

```
 /api/customer/123?prodId=xyz
```

Is there a way I could do that in just one method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you're getting a 404 Not Found when trying to hit `/api/customer`. You can make the parameter optional by adding a `?` at the end of the parameter name.

So the method signature would look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("customer/{custId?}")]
public ActionResult GetCustomers([FromRoute]string custId, [FromQuery]string prodId= "", [FromQuery]string tagNo = "")
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FromQuery` attribbute may be helpful:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("customer/{custId?}")]
public ActionResult GetCustomers(string custId, [FromQuery] string prodId = "", 
    [FromQuery] string tagNo = "")
{
}
```

This should work with every case.

Comment: Also a hint: If you want to make your endpoinds more RESTful, you should use plural forms in route (``customers``)